# Jenkins pipeline with Docker and Artifactory

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

How does one use Artifactory in a Pipeline Jenkins job with Conan, and run everything in a Docker container?

I have this `Jenkinsfile` right now:

```groovy
def LINUX_DOCKER_IMAGE = "<docker_image>"
def ARTIFACTORY_NAME = "<server-name>"
def ARTIFACTORY_REPO = "<repo-name>"
String setup_conan = "config install <git url>"

node('linux') {
  stage("Get Sources"){
    checkout scm
  }

  docker.image(LINUX_DOCKER_IMAGE) {
   def server = Artifactory.server ARTIFACTORY_NAME
   def client = Artifactory.newConanClient userHome: "/tmp/conan_home"
   def serverName = client.remote.add server: server, repo: ARTIFACTORY_REPO

    stage("Setup Conan") {
        client.run(command: setup_conan)
    }

    stage("Build package") {
        client.run(comnand: "create --profile Linux-Release . foo/bar")
    }

    stage("Upload package") {
        String command = "upload -r ${serverName} --all --check --confirm \"myproject/*\""
        def b = client.run(command: command)
        server.publishBuildInfo b
    }
  }
}
```

But the `Artifactory.newConanClient()` function fails:

```
[...]
[Pipeline] InitConanClient
[myproject] $ docker exec --env BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#19 ... <container sha> sh -c 'conan config set log.trace_file="/tmp/conan-home/conan_log.log" '
[Pipeline] ConanAddRemote
[myproject] $ docker exec --env BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#19 ... <container sha> sh -c "conan remote add <server ID> <repo url> "
WARN: Remotes registry file missing, creating default one in /tmp/conan-home/.conan/registry.txt
[Pipeline] ConanAddUser
Adding conan user '<username>', server '<server ID>'
[myproject] $ docker exec --env BUILD_DISPLAY_NAME=#19 ... <container sha> sh -c ********
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
[Pipeline] }
[...]
```

Can I setup the client differently? I can run the Conan commands in s regular `sh {}` but then how would I tell Artifactoy about it?

Comment: I've found that this is caused by a bug in the Artifactory plugin: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49697

Basically the single quote in the password does not get escaped, and the command fails because it's running in docker. This is a classic injection bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an escaping issue. Jenkins-Artifactory-plugin run Conan executable with `/bin/sh`.

There is a [Jira issue](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP-1039) for that. There you can find a snapshot which resolves the problem.

The fix will be included in the next Jenkins-Artifactory-plugin release. In the meantime, you can download the snapshot version